# CSS Hiding and Showing an element on page resize?

Tags: html, css

Can this by done with CSS? I have multiple selections on a page and will  be viewed on mobile, desktop to tablets. An easy way would just be to hide certain unnecessary elements when the page gets rezized. I know and I am  also having the elements repositioned with with div blocks.

Comment: [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: Try googling for "Responsive Web Design". That should get you started :) Here are a few suggestions of mine: **[CSS Media Queries & Using Available Space](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)**, **[Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)** and **[Creating a Mobile-First Responsive Web Design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/)**.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments point out: using CSS media queries is your answer.

Here are a few links to great resources.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

There are also available web frameworks to use, as well as differing philosophy on how to go about doing responsive web design.

http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/

Comment: @PeterFriedlander You are welcomed, please remember to "accept" an answer by clicking on the "check" or "tick" on the left side of the answer post.

Comment: I added my comment from the review page (so I didn't even see your answer). Funny how we both linked to the same 2 links. Goes to show how Chris Coyier and CSS Tricks are awesome ehe.

Comment: @Ashitaka Aye, indeed! These are our pioneers in the web development landscape doing the head-banging ahead of us, and we're just reaping the fruits of their labour. Another guy that impressed me a lot is Peter-Paul Koch with his coverage on http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/ They help to keep my sanity in check.